# Is a Masters Degree required to pursue a PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, engineering

I recently heard someone saying that you don't need a Masters to pursue a PhD. Since I have never heard of people who got PhDs without Masters, I wanted to know whether this is true and how common is it for people to get a PhD without Masters?

I would also like to know if this is true for Engineering related fields specifically. 
In other words, can someone who has just finished their undergrad apply for a PhD?

Comment: Very common in the US because a PhD program is typically 5-6 years where the first 2 correspond to a masters. Sometimes a masters is even awarded along the way, otherwise it is just awarded if you drop out.

Comment: (there are numerous other duplicates here too; try searching the site a bit)